# files not uploading in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to upload 2 files through a codeigniter controller. When i select the files and hit submit it always returns `error`. But when i do a `var_dump($_FILES);` it shows that the files are passing but not being captured by the codeigniter controller.

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong? Below is my code

```
            $config['upload_path']          = './docs/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'jpg|doc|docx';
            $config['max_size']             = 10000;
            $config['max_width']            = 3000;
            $config['max_height']           = 3000;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
if ( !$this->upload->do_upload('userfile1') || !$this->upload->do_upload('userfile2'))
{

echo "error";

} else {

$f1= $this->upload->data('userfile1');
$f2= $this->upload->data('userfile2');

echo $f1['file_name'];
echo $f2['file_name'];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple file uploading in CI please follow this way --

```
$config['upload_path']   = 'uploads/photos/'; 
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif'; 
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
for ($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['photos']['name']); $i++) { 
    $_FILES['photos[]']['name']     = $_FILES['photos']['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['photos[]']['type']     = $_FILES['photos']['type'][$i];
    $_FILES['photos[]']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $_FILES['photos[]']['error']    = $_FILES['photos']['error'][$i];
    $_FILES['photos[]']['size']     = $_FILES['photos']['size'][$i]; 
    if ($this->upload->do_upload('photos[]')) {
        $photos_files = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); 
        $photos_arr[] = $photos_files['upload_data']['file_name'];
    }else{
        $error[] = $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the reply... I have 2 separate input fields, for 2 different types of documents. So how can i get the files without using the loop?

Comment: you can define name attribute value for both input as like -- name="photo[]"